# Declare folders as idea-resource folders in a maven project?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, resources

I have a project, where I store additional resources under
`/webapp/`

After an import into Intellij Idea I have to declare this folder - as a resource folder manually.

Is there a way to declare this folder - as a resource folder, so that Idea marks it as such automatically, when this project is imported?

Comment: Have you tried to configure it manually in pom.xml: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html ?

Comment: Worked, thank you!